# "Unable to connect to server" when redirecting to https version of page

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a user account library, namely  [ulogin](http://ulogin.sourceforge.net/), working - but in the process, I'm encountering issues:

Running a certain PHP script (supplied by the library), which in part redirects the webpage to a https version of itself, causes the web browser to state that it is "unable to connect to the server". I've tried it with Opera and Firefox, and the messages are similar. "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost.". Some suggestions about the server being busy or whatnot. Pages that does not run this script works just fine.

In short, the least amount of code extracted from the library that yields this error is:

```
<?php
//Checks if we are NOT using https. It's not this line that produces the error, but I suspect omitting it will yield some sort of infinite recursion, as the first thing we'll always do will be redirecting back to the beginning.
if (!(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on')) || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https')))
    header("location:https://localhost/error.php"); //Redirects, produces "unable to connect"
echo "Everything's fine if you can see me";
?>
```

Assuming the file is called error.php, which in practice also contains the code above.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? I'm fairly new to this, and I'm not sure if I'm messing up permissions, some configuration or just missing something vital in general.

I'm on Linux Mint 17, using php5 (version "5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9") with apache2.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you setup your virtual host have you set it to listen on port 80 and port 443? Doesn't look like a php error more a issue with your server configuration not listening on port 443. Also, are you using localhost as your domain? Is this a test environment?

Comment: Are you sure your server have an SSH key (which enables HTTPS) installed?

Comment: It's a test environment. I haven't set it up to listen to either. I don't have an SSH key apparently, will try to get one.

Comment: Or wait, I'm a little tired, I don't need SSH if I'm working on a local machine, right? I'll see if I can find anything about the ports on the virtual host. Some directions are appreciated.

Comment: Some progress, Liam, now we have secure connection failed with Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long instead. Thank you for the previous advice, do you have something for this as well? I'll be working on this either way otherwise. Thank you!